# Why is tailwindcss not working when building my vite project?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, vite

I created a Vite project using the `vanilla-ts` template with `npm create vite@latest`.

I added tailwindcss with `npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer` and initialized the config files via `npx tailwindcss init -p`.

My `postcss.config.js` is the following:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

And my `tailwind.config.js` is the following:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{ts,js}', './index.html'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Within the `src` directory, I have my `main.ts` and `style.css` files. I added tailwind's directives to my `style.css` file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

And in my `main.ts` script, I import the `style.css`:

```
import './style.css';

function getElement<T extends HTMLElement>(query: string): T {
  const element = document.querySelector<T>(query);
  if (!element) throw new Error(`Element not found: ${query}`);
  return element;
}

const app = getElement<HTMLDivElement>('#app');
app.innerHTML = '>:(';
```

When I do `npm run dev`, it works flawlessly. However, when building the project with `npm run build`, tailwind is not being applied.

Pardon my naivety, but what am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question and this might not solve the exact issue you were having here, but I was having a similar issue with my TailwindCSS setup on `npm run dev`.

My project was identical - setup a new Vite vue 3 project, ran the same `npm` commands to install and setup Tailwind, the only difference was using JS instead of TS.

What worked for me was adding `.vue` files in my `tailwind.config.js` file. It took a bit of digging but the `Vue` tab on the [Tailwind vite install guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite#vue) say to do this as well, it's just not super obvious.

You can see this in the error message that TailwindCSS was giving me on `npm run dev` before I added this line:

```
warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
```

`tailwind.config.js` file with `.vue` added:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './index.html'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Great, I missed it as well, added -vue- resolve my issue...